# how to merges the content of three files (taken as input) and displays using a shell script

Tags: linux, unix

Suppose i have three file with following contents:-

File1:
Linux is OP!

File2:
Linux is good!

File3:
Linux is fun!

I want output like:
File4:
Linux is OP!
Linux is good!
Linux is fun!

Comment: [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what [`paste(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) is for:

```sh
$ paste f1 f2 f3 > f4
$ cat f4
Linux is OP! Linux is good! Linux is fun!
```

Comment: The difference between `cat` and `paste` being that `\t` is used instead of `\n` between the subsequent lines read from each stream...

Comment: @dawg Yes... with the corresponding lines thus on the same line like in OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Given your three files, you can just use `cat`:

```
$ cat f1 f2 f3
Linux is OP!
Linux is good!
Linux is fun!
```

If you want that on one line:

```
$ cat f1 f2 f3 | tr '\n' ' '
Linux is OP! Linux is good! Linux is fun!
```

Then redirect to the fourth file:

```
$ cat f1 f2 f3 | tr '\n' ' ' > f4

$ cat f4
Linux is OP! Linux is good! Linux is fun!
```